# Loop through all keys of multiple objects once?

Tags: javascript

I have an array of object-names

```
['obj','obj2','objN']
```

These objects are nodes in an object

```
{
  obj: {
    key: value,
    key2: value,
  }
  obj2:{
    key3: value
  }
...
}
```

I know that i for one object I can do:

```
for (var key in obj) {
  if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    console.log(key)
  }
}
```

but is it possible to loop through all keys of multiple objects without doing any duplicates?

Comment: Loop the Array, use the Array Keys and the *Initial Object* Property name.

Comment: If you just care about the keys only, regardless of what happens to the value, you could merge the objects together and then iterate through the keys of that one object.

Comment: what's Initial Object Property name?

Comment: It's your `?>{` and the property names are `obj:`, `obj2` ...

Comment: You mean loop through the objects (node names are mentioned) paralelly or consecutively? The first one requires promises the latter requires a list containing your objects.

Comment: Clearification: I only want to do each key once and I cant merge the objects.

Comment: Is expected result names of keys for each object ?

Comment: @guest271314 well, I'm gonna do stuff with the objects, but if I get the keys i'll be fine ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming a parent container object with the form:

```
var parentObj = 
{
    obj: {
        key: value,
        key2: value,
    }
    obj2: {
        key3: value
    }
    ...
}
```

Also if we want to include each sub-key only once,
we have

```
var objNameArray = ['obj','obj2','objN'];
var allValues = [];
var usedKeys = {};

for(var i = 0; i < objNameArray.length; ++i){
    // If the parent object does not have a matching sub-object, skip to the
    // next iteration of the loop
    if(!parentObj[objNameArray[i]]) {
        continue;
    }
    var currentObj = parentObj[objNameArray[i]];
    var subKeys = Object.keys(currentObj);
    for(var j = 0; j < subKeys.length; ++j) {
        if(usedKeys[subKeys[j]]) {
            continue;
        }
        usedKeys[subKeys[j]] = true;
        allValues.push(currentObj[subKeys[j]]);
    }
}
```

All the values from all the keys in each sub-object will then be in the array `allValues`, and all the keys from each sub-object will be available by calling `Object.keys(usedKeys);`. Note that if sub-objects can also have sub-objects, this strategy needs to be adapted to support recursion.

Answer (score 0):

If interpret Question correctly, try utilizing `Object.keys()`

```js
var data = {
  obj: {
    key: 1,
    key2: 2,
  },
  obj2:{
    key3: 3
  }
};

for (var key in data) {
  console.log(Object.keys(data[key]))
}
```

Comment: won't this run the same keys multiple times if they exist in both obj and obj2?

Comment: @Himmators Is requirement to return only unique keys ?, or, if `obj2` had  `key2` , do not return `key2` it as part of result ? , as `key2` previously iterated at `obj` ? What is expected result ?